# Call destructor on back button or on closing the application?

Tags: c++, qt, memory-management

I built an app using Qt. It includes some screens, and some of them are allocated dynamically.
I'm thinking whether to `delete` dynamically allocated objects at onBackButton() or just in their makers' destructors.

Here's the thing:

If they're deleted in onBackButton(), this will save memory because as long as the screen is not shown, memory won't be used. But, this means if we close the application while we're in one of those screens, the memory won't be deallocated.

On the other hand, if we delete them on their makers' destructors, the memory will be deallocated when the application exists. But memory will still be used even if we're not in that screen (if we entered such a screen, then pressed back, memory will still be used).

And of course we can't `delete` in both locations. This will throw exceptions.

I went with the first option because the only way to "close (exist)" the app is by physically pressing the power button on the device - which will turn off the device.
So no harm taken - next time we turn on the device everything will be fine.

Is my approach correct or is there anything better I can do?

Answer (score 3):

Well, if your application is the only thing running on that device, then as you mentioned, on application close the device will shut down, so no problem.

But as a better practice, I think you can use Qt's memory cleanup system. It works like this that any instance of a QObject will delete all its child QObjects on its own deletion. So you would just need to set up the parent of your windows and set the top of this parental hierarchy the QApp instance. This way on application quite every one of them will be destroyed properly.

Also, You can of course delete an object in more than one place, as long as you set the pointer to `nullptr` so the next delete won't raise any exception.

But a better approach could be using `QPointer` to hold the pointer, then it would be null whenever you delete the object.

Another approach could be using new c++11 `std::shared_ptr` but you have to post some code to illustrate your situation better.

Answer (score 1):

For `QObject` (and subclasses) you probably should use (i.e. invoke) the [deleteLater](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#deleteLater) slot.

> The object will be deleted when control returns to the event loop

Comment: I think he's talking about where to call the delete or deleteLater() function. So it doesn't make any difference how he deletes the object. Since the next time will most probably happen after current event loop.